# How to check hasclass when using for loop

Tags: jquery

```
<div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="4">
   <section id="topping_tsection_4">
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>

            <section class="secclass"><a  topping_id="1"  topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive" >Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a>
         </section>

         <section class="secclass"><a  topping_id="2"  topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive" >Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a>
         </section>
      </aside>


      <aside>

         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity 2</h6>
         <section class="secclass"><a qt_val="111" top_price="25"  >Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a>
         </section>

         <section class="secclass"><a qt_val="111" top_price="25"   class="tpActive">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a>
         </section>

      </aside>
   </section>
</div>
```

Hi,

This is  my HTML Response ,On click of a button i am trying to get the attribute value of top_price of the last aside section

I tried it this way but its not workng

http://jsfiddle.net/6y6h7/1/

```
     $(document).on("click", ".work", function() {

var id_attr_val=4;

$(this).find(".Topping-details").find('section#topping_tsection_'+id_attr_val+' aside:last').find('.tpActive').each(function () {
    var top_price = $(this).attr("top_price");
    alert(top_price);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `.Topping-details` are not descendants of the clicked button(`.work`), you need to do a document wide search to find those elements instead of trying to find those elements within the clicked element

```
$(".Topping-details").find('section#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val + ' aside:last').find('.tpActive').each(function () {
    var top_price = $(this).attr("top_price");
    console.log(top_price);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4y3KC/1/)

But since Id of an element must be unique, you can use just search for the target element with the id-selector

```
$('#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val + ' aside:last').find('.tpActive').each(function () {
    var top_price = $(this).attr("top_price");
    console.log(top_price);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4y3KC/)